# 'classes' is missing in props validation - Linting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am experiencing some issue with the linting. It has always worked but today is complaining about the props "classes".
I am using React Hooks.

My components have this structure

```
import { withStyles, WithStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  firstProps: string
  secondProps: number
  thirdProps: Function
}

const MyComponent = ({
  classes,
  firstProps,
  secondProps
  thirdProps
}: Props) => {
  ...my code...
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent)
```

I understand that I should pass the `classes` in the interface such as:

```
interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  firstProps: string
  secondProps: number
  thirdProps: Function
  classes: {
  ... all my classes ..
  }
}
```

BUT this is something that I want to avoid because is crumbersome AND because I think `export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent)` should be enough (as it were before today).

With the current code, I am getting a lot of lint errors such as:

```
'classes' is missing in props validation
'classes.img' is missing in props validation
'classes.currentSelect' is missing in props validation
'classes.todayDate' is missing in props validation
```

Comment: You don't declare your component to be a react functional component and pass the generic type parameter.

Comment: I am not sure what you refer to. I am using hooks in my React App, so all components should be functional

Comment: You are passing in a classes prop that doesn't appear in your property definition so of course the linter is going to complain. I'm surprised the type-checker lets this compile: it doesn't pass muster in the TS playground.

Comment: I do no think that is a problem. It follows the documentation on MUI for TypeScript to avoid repeating all the classes thanks to `WithStyles` (different from `withStyles`).
https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/ In particular when they say: "We provide a type operator WithStyles"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

In `package.json` change `"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.17.0",` to  `"eslint-plugin-react": "7.20.0"`

Answer (score 1):

It will be more helpful in how to use **style**

https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hooks why not use makeStyles?

https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api

And if you are using it with typescript I would recommend using it with createStyles()

https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#createstyles-styles-styles